# SQL - Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, error-handling

I am trying to convert data type of one of my columns (the table was imported from Excel), and then it shows an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[games_activity_2020$]
ALTER COLUMN [Version] float
```

What can I do differently?

Comment: Some string values are probably not convertable to numbers

Comment: My values are decimal numbers (3.34 for example)

Comment: Really? Every single one of them? Not a single row has something like `v0.1` or `2.3.4` in it?

Comment: I do have values like: 3.35.1 - float isn't the right type?

Comment: @MichalDavid . . . Your question should have sample data and desired results.  We don't know what you want to do with the data, but a string seems quite reasonable.  I might suggest that you delete this question and ask a new one.

Comment: @MichalDavid: If you data contains values like 3.35.1, you cannot convert to float. Float is a "floating point" number, which means it consists of a numeric part and an exponent which basically tells you where to put the comma.

you might want to take a look at https://csharpindepth.com/articles/FloatingPoint or wikipedia to read up on floating point numbers

Answer (score 0):

probably there might be any character values inserted in the table while importing from excel. You can check those values using the below query

```
SELECT version  
from   [dbo].[games_activity_2020$] 
where TRY_CONVERT(float, version) IS NULL
```

you can update those values and try to ALTER the table again

Comment: Still does not work ): I have values like: 3.35.1 - float isn't the right type?

Comment: No. I think you should use VARCHAR datatype to store this kind of data

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[games_activity_2020$]
WHERE TRY_CAST([Version] as FLOAT) IS NULL
```

and fix up any problematic values

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? This answer doesn't "fix" anything, it simply identifies values that will not parse to float. *what to do about those problems is for you to decide* - the database can't decide for you, and neither can i